A problem on a transitive group action
Let $G$ be a group that acts transitively on a set $X$ and let $x \in X$. Prove that there exists a bijection between the set of $G$-congruences of $X$ and the set of the subgroups $H$ of $G$ that contain the stabilizer of $x$.
My idea is to use an $H$ subgroup to define the following congruence in $X$:
$$x \sim y \iff \text{exists} \quad h \in H \quad \text{such that} \quad x^h=y.$$
But I can't prove that it is a $G$-congruence. Any suggestions?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please use MathJax. Here is a
tutorial.

A $G$-congruence is an equivalent relation on $X$ "preserved by $G$", namely such that $x\sim y \Longrightarrow gx\sim gy$ for every $g\in G$. Would you agree on this definition?

You really shouldn't use $x$ to mean two different things. At the very least, it is bound to be confusing. You have $x$ a fixed element of $X$ that determines a specific subgroup of $G$, and $H$ contains that subgroup. You should not define the equivalence you are trying to describe using the letter $x$ as a generic element.

Given a $G$-congruence $\sim$ on $X$, we can consider for which $g\in G$ we have $x\sim gx$.
Note if $x\sim g_1 x$ and $x\sim g_2 x$ then we have $g_1 x \sim g_1g_2x$, so by transitivity we have $x\sim g_1g_2x$.
Also $x\sim gx$ implies $g^{-1}x\sim x$ which gives us $x\sim g^{-1}x$ by symmetry.  Thus we have a subgroup $$H_\sim=\{g\in G|\,\, x\sim gx\}.$$
Reflexivity of $\sim$ tells us that $x\sim gx$ whenever $g$ is in the stabiliser of $x$.  thus $$H_\sim\supseteq {\rm Stab}(x).$$
Note given $H_\sim$ we can recover $\sim$: $$g_1x\sim g_2x \iff x\sim {g_1}^{-1}g_2x \iff  {g_1}^{-1}g_2 \in H_\sim.$$
Thus the map from $G$-congruences to subgroups of $G$ containing Stab$(x)$: $$\sim\mapsto H_\sim,$$ is injective.  To see that it is surjective, let $H\subseteq G$ be a subgroup containing Stab$(x)$.  Define a relation $\sim$ by $y \sim z$ if and only if $y=gx$ and $z=ghx$ for some $g\in G, h\in H$.
Given $y\in X$ we have $y=gx$ and $y=gex$, where $e\in H$ is the identity, and $g\in G$. Thus $\sim$ is reflexive.
If $g\in G$ and $h\in H$ then $gh\in G$ and $h^{-1}\in H$, so $\sim$ is symmetric.
If $g\in G$ and $h\in H$ and $ghx=kx$ and $j\in H$, then $gh=kt$ for $t\in {\rm Stab(x)}\subseteq H$, so $kj=ktt^{-1}j=ght^{-1}j$, where $ht^{-1}j\in H$.  Thus $\sim$ is transitive.
Thus $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on $X$.  If $g\in G$ and $h\in H$ then $kg\in G$ for any $k\in G$. Thus $\sim$ is a $G$-congruence.
It remains only to show $H=H_\sim$: We have $k\in H_\sim$ if and only if there exists $g\in {\rm stab}(x)$ and $h\in H$ such that $kx=ghx$, which happens if and only if $k=ghg'$ with $g,g'\in {\rm stab}(x)$ and $h\in H$, which happens if and only if $k\in H$.

Very clear! Anyway I cannot convince myself that I can recover $\sim$ from $H_\sim$. I really don't see how the following is the original G-congruence                                                                                                                             $$g_1x\sim g_2x \iff x\sim {g_1}^{-1}g_2x \iff  {g_1}^{-1}g_2 \in H_\sim.$$

The original $G$- congruence is $G$ invariant, which gives us the first implication (both ways), and the definition of $H_\sim$ gives us the second implication (both ways).  Thus just knowing $H_\sim$ we can recover the original $G$-congruence.  Given $g_1x,g_2x$, we know if they are related just from knowing if $g_1^{-1}g_2\in H_\sim$.
